# string.Contains with Linq To Sql return an Null exception

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

My Linq To Sql query

```
PROJETS = PROJETS.Where(p => (p.VilleArrive != "" && p.VilleArrive != null) &&  p.VilleArrive.Contains(alerte.VilleArrive));
```

is translated like this

```
SELECT * // (many columns)
FROM [dbo].[cov_Projet] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[VilleArrive] <> @p0)     // city != ""
AND ([t0].[VilleArrive] IS NOT NULL)  // city != null
AND ([t0].[VilleArrive] LIKE @p1)     // city.contains(alert.city)
ORDER BY [t0].[DateDebut]
```

It is well executed when i run it manually into sql server. But it returns a ArgumentNullException exception when executed by linq.
Actually the column tested "VilleArrive" ("city") is never null but always an empty string

I really don't understand why it appends.
My problem looks like this one [LINQ to SQL and Null strings, how do I use Contains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977159/linq-to-sql-and-null-strings-how-do-i-use-contains)
but answers do not work with me.

The "LIKE" keyword seems to invoke the Linq.SqlClient.SqlHelpers.GetStringContainsPattern(String text, Char escape)

Thank you for your help , sorry for my english.

Here the stack trace my project is an ASP MVC 1.0 project

> System.ArgumentNullException was
>   unhandled by user code   Message="La
>   valeur ne peut pas être null.\r\nNom
>   du paramètre : text"
>   Source="System.Data.Linq"
>   ParamName="text"   StackTrace:
>          à System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlHelpers.GetStringContainsPattern(String
>   text, Char escape)
>          à System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.PostBindDotNetConverter.Visitor.TranslateStringMethod(SqlMethodCall
>   mc)
>          à System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.PostBindDotNetConverter.Visitor.VisitMethodCall(SqlMethodCall
>   mc)
>          à System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode
>   node)
>          à System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitExpression(SqlExpression
>   exp)
>          à System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitBinaryOperator(SqlBinary
>   bo)
>          à System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.PostBindDotNetConverter.Visitor.VisitBinaryOperator(SqlBinary
>   bo)
>          à System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode
>   node)
>          à System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitExpression(SqlExpression
>   exp)
>          à System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitSelectCore(SqlSelect
>   select)
>          à System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.PostBindDotNetConverter.Visitor.VisitSelect(SqlSelect
>   select)
>          à System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode
>   node)
>          à System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitAlias(SqlAlias
>   a)
>          à System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode
>   node)
>          à System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitSource(SqlSource
>   source)
>          à System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitSelectCore(SqlSelect
>   select)
>          à System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.PostBindDotNetConverter.Visitor.VisitSelect(SqlSelect
>   select)
>          à System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode
>   node)
>          à System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitUnion(SqlUnion
>   su)
>          à System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode
>   node)
>          à System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitAlias(SqlAlias
>   a)
>          à System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode
>   node)
>          à System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitSource(SqlSource
>   source)
>          à System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitSelectCore(SqlSelect
>   select)
>          à System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.PostBindDotNetConverter.Visitor.VisitSelect(SqlSelect
>   select)
>          à System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode
>   node)
>          à System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery(ResultShape
>   resultShape, Type resultType, SqlNode
>   node, ReadOnlyCollection`1
>   parentParameters, SqlNodeAnnotations
>   annotations)
>          à System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery(Expression
>   query, SqlNodeAnnotations annotations)
>          à System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.GetQueryText(Expression
>   query)
>          à System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.ToString()
>          à covCake.Services.ProjetAlerts.RetrieveProjectsByUsers(Boolean
>   UpdateAlerts) dans
>   D:\AspProject\covCake\covCake\Services\ProjetAlerts.cs:ligne
>   111
>          à covCake.Controllers.AlertesController.SendAlertEmail(String
>   p) dans
>   D:\AspProject\covCake\covCake\Controllers\AlertesController.cs:ligne
>   152
>          à lambda_method(ExecutionScope , ControllerBase , Object[] )
>          à System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters)
>          à System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)
>          à System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor
>   actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)
>          à System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClassa.b__7()
>          à System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext
>   preContext, Func`1 continuation)
>   InnerException:

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `!= ""` comparison, and make sure the parameter you are passing isn't null:

```
PROJETS = PROJETS.Where(p => (p.VilleArrive != null) &&
                             (alerte.VilleArrive != null) &&
                              p.VilleArrive.Contains(alerte.VilleArrive));
```