# LINQ to Entities and null strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I've got quite a strange thing happening on an ASP.NET 4.0 web application using EF 4.0 as its database backend.  Essentially, I've got a table that stores users' password reset requests (containing a reset key of type `byte[]`, an expiry of type `DateTime`, and a foreign key to a `User` containing a `string Email` and `string Name`).  Some users do not have an email address set, so for a `PasswordRequest request`, `request.Email` is `null`.

Here's the problem.  This works perfectly fine:

```cs
string u = Request["u"];
string e = Request["e"];

var requests = from r in context.PasswordRequests
               where r.User.Name == u && r.User.Email == null && r.Expiry >= DateTime.Now
               select r;
```

I get the expected number of results (nonzero, since there are entries with `null` emails).

But this always returns an empty collection when `e` is `null`:

```cs
string u = Request["u"];
string e = Request["e"];

var requests = from r in context.PasswordRequests
               where r.User.Name == u && r.User.Email == e && r.Expiry >= DateTime.Now
               select r;
```

The only thing that I got to work properly (which doesn't logically make any sense) is this:

```cs
string u = Request["u"];
string e = Request["e"];

IQueryable<PasswordRequest> requests;

if (e == null)
    requests = from r in context.PasswordRequests
               where r.User.Name == u && r.User.Email == null && r.Expiry >= DateTime.Now
               select r;
else
    requests = from r in context.PasswordRequests
               where r.User.Name == u && r.User.Email == e && r.Expiry >= DateTime.Now
               select r;
```

I'm absolutely stumped.  Any ideas?

Comment: The Email field in your actual table, is it declared as a NULL column?

Comment: Can you post the generated sql?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Basically this is a mismatch between SQL and C# when it comes to the handling of nulls. You don't need to use two queries, but you need:

```
where r.User.Name == u && (r.User.Email == e ||
                           (e == null && r.User.Email == null))
```

It's annoying, and there may be a helper function to make life easier, but it fundamentally comes from SQL's null handling where

```
where X = Y
```

will *not* match if both X and Y are null. (Whereas in C# the equivalent expression would be true.)

You may need to do the same for `u` as well, unless that is non-nullable in the database.

One small trick you could at least *try* if you're happy with null and empty strings being handled the same way is:

```
// Before the query
e = e ?? "";

// In the query
where r.User.Name == u && (r.User.Email ?? "") == e
```

I believe that will perform null coalescing on both the email column and `e`, so you never end up comparing null with anything.

Comment: Aha!  I though it might come to that, but I wasn't sure exactly what caused that.  Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Nicely done! The where condition is a bit loose. So I guess putting in all three possible values for `e` make sense.

Comment: I had a problem where my database contained a INT column that allowed nulls, so some of the other solutions wouldn't work for me (most solutions deal with strings) - your last bit of code saved my life! thanks!  Here's what i ended up using: (w.AccountID ?? _AccountID) == _AccountID

Comment: This should be considered a bug in Linq to Entities (or Linq to sql - it happens there too). Is this open on Connect? I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Ok, found it, and it seems to be fixed in some newer versions of EF: http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015361-incorrect-handling-of-null-variables-in-where-cl?ref=title%23suggestion-1015361

Answer (score 3):

I have found a couple of articles detailing the same issue. Unfortunately, I haven't faced this issue so far. It is very interesting though.

Here:

[LINQ syntax where string value is not null or empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368946/linq-syntax-where-string-value-is-not-null-or-empty)

[LINQ to SQL and Null strings, how do I use Contains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977159/linq-to-sql-and-null-strings-how-do-i-use-contains)

And from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882535.aspx

Comment: Useful links.  Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer using method (lambda) syntax as I do, you could do it like this:

```
var result = new TableName();

using(var db = new EFObjectContext)
{
    var query = db.TableName;

    query = value1 == null 
        ? query.Where(tbl => tbl.entry1 == null) 
        : query.Where(tbl => tbl.entry1 == value1);

    query = value2 == null 
        ? query.Where(tbl => tbl.entry2 == null) 
        : query.Where(tbl => tbl.entry2 == value2);

    result = query
        .Select(tbl => tbl)
        .FirstOrDefault();

   // Inspect the value of the trace variable below to see the sql generated by EF
   var trace = ((ObjectQuery<REF_EQUIPMENT>) query).ToTraceString();

}

return result;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to retrieve items from the DB when request['e'] == null

it should have been

```
var requests = from r in context.PasswordRequests
               where r.User.Name == u && r.User.Email is null && r.Expiry >= DateTime.Now
               select r;
```

note that == null and is null is different . see --> [MSDN Info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738687.aspx)

Therefore, your last example is sort of valid since you need 2 ways to get data from the DB. i.e. one if email is null and one if email == Request['e']